# PowerShell Strings

Tags: string

I extract some data from my computer and it creates either a variable or I've written it to a .txt file.  The output looks like this:

RVR7RYR

RVR7RYR

I I only need the first 7 characters so I wrote this:

```
$line = get-content "c:\temp\file.txt"
$var = $line
$result = $var.SubString($var.length - 7, 7)
$result
```

It gives me this error:

Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:5 char:1

- $result = $var.SubString($var.length - 7, 7)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  ```

my file does have spaces inbetween the values and even after the second value, not sure if that matters.

how do I get just the first 7 characters?

Comment: 1) First (as a debugging method), `echo` "$var" and $var.length" to make sure they're really what you think they are. 2) Q: Why not simply `$result = $var.SubString(0, 7)`?

Comment: Hello.  when I echo "$var" it shows me both occurrences of the string.    When I run "$result = $var.SubString(0,7) I get the exact same error as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for trying; sorry it didn't help.  Let me try to reproduce the problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were inadvertently reading an *ARRAY*, not just a single text string.

**.ps1:**

```
$line = get-content "c:\temp\file.txt" 
echo "line: " $line ", line.length: " $line.length ", line[0].length: " $line[0].length
$result = $line[0].SubString(0, 7)
echo "result: " $result
```

**Sample output:**

```
line:
RVR7RYR

RVR7RYR

cow pig chicken goat
, line.length:
5
, line[0].length:
7
result:
RVR7RYR
```

In other words, you want to take the first 7 characters of the first line (`$line[0]`).